# R duplicated command

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a dataset where I need to find duplicates based on data in multiple columns. An example is below, data types are int, date, int.

Something like

```
DF1 <- data.frame(ID=c('1','1','3','4','3' ),
        Date=c('01-04-2016','01-05-2016','01-04-2016','01-06-2016', '01-04-2016'),
        Sale=c('1000','1000','1000','2000', '1000'))
```

I know I can use the duplicated command to find dupes based on 1 variable as follows

```
DF1$dupes <- duplicated(DF1$ID)
```

But when I include more than one variable, like:

```
DF1$dupes <- duplicated(DF1, c("ID", "Date", "Sale"))
```

I get errors for both

```
argument 'incomparables != FALSE' is not used (yet)
```

and

```
'fromLast' must be TRUE or FALSE
```

Can someone please explain to me what those mean? I have read documentation at ?duplicated, and many online sites, most of which are carbon copies of the help documentation.

Incomparables -

- a vector of values that cannot be compared. FALSE is a special value,
  meaning that all values can be compared, and may be the only value
  accepted for methods other than the default. It will be coerced
  internally to the same type as x.

fromLast -

- logical indicating if duplication should be considered from the
  reverse side, i.e., the last (or rightmost) of identical elements
  would correspond to duplicated = FALSE.

Two things:

1. Can someone explain why it won't work? I don't understand and it'd be helpful to understand.
2. Is there another method to ID them? I do not want to remove them, I want to ID them within the dataframe, a simple 1/0 would work just fine.

Help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I think there is some mistakes  You need to subset the columns of the dataset and then apply the duplicated  `duplicated(DF1[ c("ID", "Date", "Sale")])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is that the OP is using "ID", "Date" and "Sale" as arguments of `duplicated`.  According to `?duplicated`

```
duplicated(x, incomparables = FALSE,
       fromLast = FALSE, nmax = NA, ...)
```

Here, 'x' is  a vector or a data frame or an array or NULL.
 The second argument is `incomparables` and it assumes that `c("ID", "Date", "Sale")` is the second argument, w

---

We need to subset the dataset and pass as argument for 'x' and apply the `duplicated` instead

```
duplicated(DF1[ c("ID", "Date", "Sale")])
```

Comment: The syntax is helpful, thank you. But I need this to be a variable IN the dataframe, not just print out in the console. When I run something like DF1$dupes <- and then the rest of your syntax, it does not create a new variable for me.

Comment: @Adam_S  You just need to assign `<-` i.e. `DF1$newvariable <- duplicated(DF1[ c("ID", "Date", "Sale")])`  The output of `duplicated` is a logical vector and it should work unless you assigned your object to something else

Comment: Not sure my problem, I just ran it again and it worked. Might be one of the n00b-est questions I have ever asked here. Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to find the duplicates based on just 1 of the `columns`:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(ID=c('1','1','3','4','3' ),
                    Date=c('01-04-2016','01-05-2016','01-04-2016','01-06-2016', '01-04-2016'),
                    Sale=c('1000','1000','1000','2000', '1000'))

findDupes <- function(theVector){
    dupes <- theVector[duplicated(theVector)];
    return (dupes);
}

dupesID <- findDupes(DF1$ID)
```

This produces the following output:

```
> dupesID
 [1] 1 3
```

Comment: Potentially useful, but I need to be able to specify more than one variable to use to find duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not passing valid arguments to the function: you are passing `c("ID", "Date", "Sale")` as argument to "incomparables" (as you can see in the docs, incomparables is the second argument to the duplicated function).

What are you exactly trying to accomplish? Mark all rows that have a duplicate in any of the columns? You can use

```
DF1$dupes <- apply(sapply(DF1, duplicated), MARGIN = 1, any)
```

or if you only want to indicate duplicates in any of a subset of your colums, use

```
DF1$dupes <- apply(sapply(DF1[,c("ID", "Date")], duplicated), MARGIN = 1, any)
```

instead.

or if you want to mark duplicates for each column individually, use

```
DF1 <- cbind(DF1, sapply(DF1, duplicated))
```